# How to gray out SwiftUI's keyboard return key

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, keyboard, textfield

I'm trying to **disable the send key** in SwiftUI when there is no text in the textfield. Does anyone knows how to achieve this effect in SwiftUI using `Textfield`?

```
 TextField("", text: $text)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately in SwiftUI we have to do things the way it wants them to be done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In UIKit we could've used this modifier to disable return key for a textfield it it's text was empty - read here :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624432-enablesreturnkeyautomatically

However in SwiftUI there is no such modifier at present, instead you could do something like this:

```
@State private var istextInputted = false
@State private var text = ""

    TextField("Type Here", text: $text)
        .onChange(of: text, perform: { value in
            istextInputted = value.count > 0
        })
        .submitLabel(.done)
        .onSubmit {
            if !istextInputted {
                return
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .padding()
```

if your text is empty then on submit it will just return void.